# NUXT: Redirect with payload

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm trying to create rather common thing, let's think it's a blog. On client side click on post card opens modal with post's content and adds a query `?postID=123` to URL.

When we try visiting `my-site.com?postID=123`, a server middleware checks if there is `postID` query parameter and redirects us to `my-site.com/category/subcategory/123` with 301 redirect. This middleware could look like this:

```
export default async function ({ route, redirect, api }) {
  const postID = route.query.postID;
  if (!postID) return;

  const post = await api.get('postID')

  redirect(301, `/${post.category}/${post.subcategory}/${postID}`);
}
```

It works but to build link with category and subcategory I've already got my post. And on `_post` page we are redirected to I have to get my post again in `asyncData()` or `fetch()`.

I can put post to the store in `nuxtServerInit` action, but in my opinion it's a little bit hack.

So the question is: Is there any way to pass some data to page component during redirect?

Comment: If i get it good, you could do a middleware in nuxt that catch all redirects and you could pass data or query params there then

Comment: @DarioRega how should I pass data to page component with 'redirect' function?

Comment: Could you tell me more about the data you want to pass ? write an example and i try to adapt my answer based on your code

Comment: @elijah-ellanski I have implemented a similar task using a redirect. Have you successfully solved the problem? If so, how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe YES, you can do it. But you need to know a few things.
If you have a named route, it is simpler. Just do the following:

```js
    // pass params to named route
    this.$router.push ({name: 'user', params: {userId: '123'}})
    
    // get params from named route in other component
    console.log(this.$router.params)
```

However if you don't have a named route created you can do something less elegant, but it will work...

It would be interesting to take a look at the vue documentation at this link https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html. Here is a lot of information explaining this better.

But let's go to the example, supposing that you use router.push, and that you understand that it is possible to execute a function after the replace occours, say that you could do something like this:

```js
this.$router.push(
{
  path: 'YOUR/PATH',
},
// onComplete Function
(myValue) => {

    // save the value in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('VALUE', JSON.stringify(myValue))

  // to retrieve the value you can get with
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('VALUE')))

  // save the value in store with vuex
  this.$store.dispatch('doSomethingFromAction', myValue)
  this.$store.commit('doSomethingFromMutation', myValue)

  // to retrieve the value you can get with
  console.log(this.$store.state.myValue)
})
```

If you don't know vuex, take a look in the docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: I need to pass data to page component on server side, localStorage is not an option

Comment: So, then you can create a specific router name inside your nuxt.config.js, you will need configure the router property to pass some value as a query, or params. The first option in my anwser is this. take a look in the vue documentation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html here you will get what you need.

Comment: The idea was not to mess with URL. just passing data as third argument of redirect function encodes it as querystring, that's right

Comment: Sorry but what you looking for does't exist at this momment